# Power BI ( PowerQuery) - Checking if values from three columns exist in three other columns

Tags: conditional-statements, powerbi, relational-database, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm pretty new to PowerQuery I'm facing a little issue. I have two tables in powerquery with the following structures ( samples ):

Table 1 ( model )

| PSET | Parameter | Attribute |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PSet_Location | PM_MacroArea&FloorCode | 7 |
| PSet_Location | PM_MacroArea&FloorDescription | Roof |

Table 2 ( rules )

| PSET | Parameter | AttributeRight | PSET.rule | Parameter.rule | Attribute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PSet_Location | PM_MacroArea&FloorCode | 99 | PSet_Location | PM_MacroArea&FloorDescription | Roof |
| PSet_Location | PM_MacroArea&FloorCode | 7 | PSet_Location | PM_MacroArea&FloorDescription | First level |
| PSet_Location | PM_MacroArea&FloorCode | 1 | PSet_Location | PM_MacroArea&FloorDescription | Second level |

To put it in simple words, the first table is "the model of a building". A PSET is a set of properties, a set can have more than one parameter and a parameter can have more than one value.

The second table is a "Rule check" table. The last three columns represent a "rule". For example, if "PSetLocation" "PMMacroArea&FloorDescription" and "Roof" exist in the first table (first condition) then "PSetLocation" "PM*MacroArea&FloorCode" need to have 99 as attribute (second condition).
*
I would like to create a custom function to add as a new column in Table1 that applies these checks. If both condition are met I get "True", if only the first one is met I get "False" otherwise "null". In my example, I'd get "FALSE" as output in the first row of my new column because "PSetLocation" "PM_MacroArea&FloorDescription" and "Roof" exist but I have 7 instead of 99.

I've merged both table by using "PSET" and "Parameter" and expanded "AttributeRight" "PSET.rule" "Parameter.rule" and "Attribute.rule" and used the following function :

```
= (Table as table) =>
    Table.AddColumn(#"Tabella valutazione", "Verifica regola",
        each let
            condition1 = 
                List.Contains(Table.Column(#"Tabella valutazione", "PSET"), [PSET.relazione])
                and List.Contains(Table.Column(#"Tabella valutazione", "Parametro"), [Parametro.relazione])
                and List.Contains(Table.Column(#"Tabella valutazione", "Attributo"), [Valore.relazione]),
            condition2 = [Attributo] = [AttributoCheck]
            in
        if condition1 and condition2 then
            true
        else if condition1 then
            false
        else 
            null
)
```

Here's an example of the result I need:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnIur.png)
[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0VYj.png)

The output is the one I want but I have to duplicate my tables then merge it back to my first table to avoid any cyclic referrence error and my model becomes pretty slow ( I have millions of rows ). To conclude, a custom function to use a new column seemed like a good idea but I don't know how to proceed !I hope I was clear enough, thanks in advance :)

Comment: I am unable to see how to get where you want from your sample data file.io/DwOIwA6iEiIl Please explain in more detail for us to help

Comment: @horseyride I simply need to add a fourth column in my first table that verifies my conditions.

I firstly need to check if PSET.rule | Parametre.rule | Attribute.rule ( second table ) exist in the first table. If they do, I need to verify that "AttributeRight" is equal to "Attribute" in my first table.

In my example you can see that the combination PSet_Location | PM_MacroArea&FloorDescription | Roof exist in my first table, it means that PSet_Location | PM_MacroArea&FloorCode needs to have 99 as attribute and not 7 as in my first example.

I uploaded screenshots. Thanks in advanced !

Comment: Sorry, perhaps someone else can help you. Ron and David are usually good with interpretation